# re-write active record query to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, rails

I want to rewrite the active record query to Actual PostgreSQL query

```
Camera.joins("left JOIN users on cameras.owner_id = users.id")
                    .joins("left JOIN vendor_models vm on cameras.model_id = vm.id")
                    .joins("left JOIN vendors v on vm.vendor_id = v.id")
                    .where(condition).order(sorting(col_for_order, order_for))
```

as you can see how these tables are related in the above joins.

also conditions could be

```
"lower(cameras.exid) like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%') OR lower(cameras.name) like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%') OR
      lower(vm.name) like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%') OR lower(v.name) like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%')
      OR lower(users.firstname || ' ' || users.lastname) like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%') OR
      lower(cameras.config->>'external_host') like lower('%#{params[:fquery]}%')
```

Reason of writing this query, I have another table `camera_shares` which is related to cameras table with `camera_id`, I also want to get the count of camera_shares against a camera_id, How could that be possible to geth the similar results in PostgreSQL

Comment: Is `camera_id` `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about all your condition stuff but going on your textual description of the problem..

> Reason of writing this query, I have another table camera_shares which is related to cameras table with camera_id, I also want to get the count of camera_shares against a camera_id, How could that be possible to geth the similar results in PostgreSQL

You'll want something like this...

```
SELECT camera_id, count(*)
FROM cameras AS c
JOIN camera_shares AS cs
  USING (camera_id)
GROUP BY camera_id;
```